# Delay function call

Tags: javascript, jquery

**My problem:**
I have two js files, the first file being loaded is calling functions that are on the second file before it's loaded. As a result I am getting an error that says "is not a function" an rightfully so because it does not exist yet.

**My Question:**
Is there a way to delay the function call until the second file is loaded?

**My attempt:**

```
$.getScript("manualEntryCalculations.js", function(){
          hPFt();
});

var hPFt = function() {
  var val = hpDim(); //H25
  var val2 = speedRad1(); //H21
  var val3 = dift(); //H20
  var val4 = Math.pow(val2, 2);
  var val5 = val * val4;
  var val6 = Math.pow(val3, 2);
  var total = (val5 * val6) / 32.2 / 100;
  $('#hPFt').val(+total.toFixed(2));
  return total;
};
hPFt();
```

I tried this but encountered another issue an got the error **"hpDim();"** is not a function. that's because this function is also on the second file an has not been loaded yet.

Any help would be appreciated

```
var hpDim = function() {
     var qNondArray = qNond();
  var mySpline = new MonotonicCubicSpline(
    qNondArray, [16.60, 16.60, 16.52, 16.34, 16.17, 15.91, 15.47, 15.12, 14.77, 14.33, 13.90, 13.46]);
  var total = mySpline.interpolate(qdim());
  $('#hpDim').val(+total.toFixed(2));
  return total;
};
hpDim();
```

Comment: instead of `var hPFt =`, try `function hPTf(){}`.

Comment: Your code, as-is, should work. I assume you've left something out. Though... you do seem to be executing hPFt twice, which is a bit odd, and likely to throw an error (but still mostly work.) comment out the last line.